# List Objects Migrations in Realm for Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, realm, realm-migration

I added a list to my realm object class, and i need to migrate but i keep getting this error:

**"Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'UserIdCard.idImages' has been added."**

these are my classes:

```
class UserIdCard: Object {
    dynamic var idAccountId: Int = 0
    dynamic var idName: String = ""
    dynamic var idType: String = ""
    let idImages = List<UserImage>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "idAccountId"
    }

}

class UserImage: Object {
    dynamic var image: Data? = nil
}
```

And this is my migration code:

```
if (oldSchemaVersion < 4) {
    migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: UserImage.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
      newObject!["image"] = nil
    }
    migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: UserIdCard.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
      let image = migration.create(UserImage.className(), value: Data())
      let images = newObject?["idImages"] as? List<MigrationObject>
      images?.append(image)
    } 
}
```

I did exactly like the example Realm provided : [Link](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift-3.0/Migration/AppDelegate.swift)

Also i tried this : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307111/perform-migration-by-adding-list-and-another-model-class)
,but it's not working, i tried to pass different values in "value" field but nothing worked, what is the right way to migrate a list in realm?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you bump up the schema version after adding the field?

Comment: Yes i did that i changed it

Comment: Could you please share the whole example that reproduces this issue?

Comment: Thanks i was able to solve the issue, i was passing another configuration file to the realm